# Azure mobile services NodeJS Backend AngularJS Function not returning results

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, azure

Here's the situation.

All appropriate javascripts are loaded and called.  I can debug and step through and see that data is being retrieved from the mobile service and no errors are in the javascript console.

Issue is that the "done()" of the getTable call is called twice and the data is not returned back to the module function which calls the method so no list is created in the page.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I can't seem to see it.

Angular Controler

```js
var appModule = angular.module('myApp');

appModule.controller('clientsController', [
    "$scope", "$rootScope", "$http", "$window", "ClientsDataService", function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $window, ClientsDataService) {
        $rootScope.title = "Client List";
        $scope.clients = ClientsDataService.getAllClients();
    }
]);
```

Angular Module Function

```js
var clientModule = angular.module('myApp');

clientModule.factory("ClientsDataService", [
    '$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
        var _getAllClients = function () {
            return getAllClients();
        }

        return { "getAllClients": _getAllClients };
    }
]);
```

Azure Service Call

```
function getAllClients() {
    azureClient.getTable("Client")
        .read()
        .done(
            function (results) {
                var clientArray = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    clientArray.push({
                        "Name": results[i].ClientName,
                        "AcountExecutive": results[i].AccountExecutiveName,
                        "ClientPartner": results[i].ClientPartnerName,
                        "Revenue": results[i].RevenueInMillions,
                        "Industry": results[i].Industry,
                        "Notes": results[i].Notes,
                        "CompanyUrl": results[i].CompanyUrl,
                        "InfoUrl": results[i].InfoUrl,
                        "LogoUrl": results[i].LogoUrl,
                        "Lat": results[i].Latitude,
                        "Lng": results[i].Longitude
                    });
                }
                return JSON.stringify(clientArray);
            },
            function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `read()` function in mobile service is an async function,  and usually, we use promises and `$q` to handle asynchronous calls in AngularJS. 
Here is my test code snippets:

```
var mobileServiceClient = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://<your_mobile_service_name>.azure-mobile.net/', '<manage keys>'),
            todoItemTable = mobileServiceClient.getTable('todoitem');

 angular.module("myApp",['myApp.services'])
    .controller('clientCtrl',function($scope,ClientsDataService){
        ClientsDataService.getAllClients().then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $scope.clients = data;
        })
    });

 angular.module('myApp.services',[])
    .factory("ClientsDataService",function($http,$q){
        return {
            getAllClients : function(){
                var q = $q.defer();
                getAllClients().done(function(todoItems){
                    if(todoItems.length>0){
                        q.resolve(todoItems);
                    }else{
                        q.reject(false)
                    }
                });
                return q.promise;
            }
        }
    });
function getAllClients() {
    return todoItemTable
        .read()
        .then(
            function (todoItems) {
                return todoItems;
            },
            function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
}
```

And about your issue `getTable()` called twice, in my test on local, I can reproduce the issue only when I mark the `Disable cache` checkbox in `chrome`:
[image]

And if I unmark the checkbox or browse in IE browser, it will just call once.

If you have any concern, please let me know.

Comment: thank you for the pointer to the disable cache.  Using the defer is a path that I was looking at, however your sample code bypass's the purpose of what I'm wanting to accomplish.  I don't want the service call in the angularjs factory, I want to service call abstracted out into a separate file (decoupled so to speak).

Comment: I have update the code snippet. Please check. Any concern, fell free to let me know.